# Parsing millions of XML files - Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, out-of-memory

I was going through parsing xml techniques and decided to use SAX over DOM parser.  The data, millions of xml files of nearly 6KB each. I am using SAXparser.

I loop over all the files calling parser.parse(file,handler) one by one but after 100,000 I get a heap out of memory error. When I tried to dump my heap and read it, i saw a lot of char arrays and strings being stored.

The question is , how do I parse through millions of tiny files without heap error.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Ajinkya Jumbad
 */
public class dataset {

    static List<String> cols;
    public HashMap<String, HashMap> hm = new HashMap<>();
    static int i =0;

    dataset() {
        String coln[] = {
            "UID",
            "Name",
            "NationID",
            "Born",
            "Age",
            "IntCaps",
            "IntGoals",
            "U21Caps",
            "U21Goals",
            "Height",
            "Weight",
            "AerialAbility",
            "CommandOfArea",
            "Communication",
            "Eccentricity",
            "Handling",
            "Kicking",
            "OneOnOnes",
            "Reflexes",
            "RushingOut",
            "TendencyToPunch",
            "Throwing",
            "Corners",
            "Crossing",
            "Dribbling",
            "Finishing",
            "FirstTouch",
            "Freekicks",
            "Heading",
            "LongShots",
            "Longthrows",
            "Marking",
            "Passing",
            "PenaltyTaking",
            "Tackling",
            "Technique",
            "Aggression",
            "Anticipation",
            "Bravery",
            "Composure",
            "Concentration",
            "Vision",
            "Decisions",
            "Determination",
            "Flair",
            "Leadership",
            "OffTheBall",
            "Positioning",
            "Teamwork",
            "Workrate",
            "Acceleration",
            "Agility",
            "Balance",
            "Jumping",
            "LeftFoot",
            "NaturalFitness",
            "Pace",
            "RightFoot",
            "Stamina",
            "Strength",
            "Consistency",
            "Dirtiness",
            "ImportantMatches",
            "InjuryProness",
            "Versatility",
            "Adaptability",
            "Ambition",
            "Loyalty",
            "Pressure",
            "Professional",
            "Sportsmanship",
            "Temperament",
            "Controversy",
            "PositionsDesc",
            "Goalkeeper",
            "Sweeper",
            "Striker",
            "AttackingMidCentral",
            "AttackingMidLeft",
            "AttackingMidRight",
            "DefenderCentral",
            "DefenderLeft",
            "DefenderRight",
            "DefensiveMidfielder",
            "MidfielderCentral",
            "MidfielderLeft",
            "MidfielderRight",
            "WingBackLeft",
            "WingBackRight"};
        cols = Arrays.asList(coln);
        try {
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Ajinkya Jumbad\\Desktop\\fmdata");

            //File files[] = f.listFiles();
            for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
                //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    parse p = new parse(file);
                }
            }


            //savefile();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(dataset.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void savefile() {
        try {
            String file_name = "dataset.csv";
            FileWriter w = new FileWriter(file_name);
            writecsv ws = new writecsv();
            boolean first = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String key : cols) {
                if (!first) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                sb.append(key);
                first = false;
            }
            sb.append("\n");
            w.append(sb.toString());
            for (String uid : hm.keySet()) {
                ws.writeLine(w, hm.get(uid));
            }
            w.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class parse{
        parse(File file){
            try {
                SAXParserFactory parserfac = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                parserfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
                SAXParser parser = parserfac.newSAXParser();
                DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler(){
                    HashMap<String, String> ht;
                    @Override
                    public void startDocument() {
                        ht = new HashMap<>();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void startElement(String namespaceURI,
                            String localName,
                            String qName,
                            Attributes atts) {
                        if (atts.getValue("Value") != null && cols.contains(localName)) {
                            //System.out.println(localName);
                            String key = localName;
                            ht.put(key, atts.getValue("Value"));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void endDocument() {
                        String uid = ht.get("UID");
                        hm.put(uid, ht);
                        dataset.i += 1;
                        if(dataset.i%100 == 0){
                            System.out.println(dataset.i);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                    }

                };
                parser.parse(file, handler);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(dataset.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dataset ds = new dataset();
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Without looking at your code it's difficult to help you. A guess would be that you keep opening these files but you never close them and release the resources.

Comment: Have you tried with DOM parser as you said you are parsing file by file and each file is of just 6KB only? Try to close xml connections to free up memory resources

Comment: Adding my code, wait a sec

Comment: You are storing everything you read in a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`, and you wonder why you run out of memory after storing content of 100000 XML files? How much memory did you give Java?

Comment: Since you are writing it out to a csv file eventually, why store everything in memory? Why not just write it out to output file as your app makes progress?

Comment: yes, this is what i did afterwards. i worked. thanks

Comment: FYI for this type of heavy duty processing, get XML is worth a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, reuse the SAXParserFactory and the parser itself. Creating a SAXParserFactory can be very expensive, and creating a parser is not cheap either. Taken together, these operations probably take much longer than actually parsing the input. But that's about saving time, not memory.

As far as memory is concerned, I suspect that the space is all taken up with your own data structures: specifically the HashMap into which you put the results. Try using JVisualVM to examine the heap to confirm this.

As for the bottom line, "how do I parse this data without running out of memory", it all depends what you want to do with the data. No-one parses XML data for fun; you do it because you want to use the data for some purpose. We can't advise you on a different approach without knowing more about (a) what you want to do with the data, and (b) the volumetrics (you've given us a broad indication of scale: but you should be able to tell us how many entries you expect this HashMap to contain, and how big the entries will be).

And one other obvious little thing, in case you weren't aware of it: use the -Xmx option on the Java command line to control the amount of heap space available.

Comment: Instead of storing all values and then writing them, i simply read and wrote data one by one. Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

A; close the files after you are done.

B; if it still happens, keep track of free memory and call gc(). Kind of a hack, but if it works..

C; If you have access to multiple threads, run this on as many as possible; give each thread a number N and have it handle every Nth file.

Comment: I never open file, note that i java.io.File has no close method because it does not actually open a file rather it is a *pointer to a file?*

Comment: You may want to look at what SAXParser is doing to read the file. Somewhere the file is being opened, regardless of what is doing it.